# C++ Cleaning up memory in a try catch block without using a smart pointer.

Tags: c++, exception

I am adding Exceptions in to an existing code base. In this example the `DoAction()` function creases some memory and calls a sub function `ExceptionFnk()` that throws an exception.

The `DoAction()` function needs to clean up the memory that was created before passing up the exception to the higher levels to be handled correctly.

Consider the following code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <exception>
#include <string>    

class CFooBase {
    public:
        static unsigned int _id ; 
        CFooBase( )  { printf( "Created CFooBase (%d)\n", ++CFooBase::_id ); }
        ~CFooBase( ) { printf( "Destroy CFooBase (%d)\n", CFooBase::_id-- ); }
};
unsigned int CFooBase::_id ; 

class ExceptionBar: public std::exception 
{
    public:
        const char* what() const throw() { return std::string( "ExceptionBar").c_str() ; }
        int Get() { return 99; }
};

// this function just throws an exception. 
void ExceptionFnk() {
    throw ExceptionBar( ); 
}

void DoAction() {

    CFooBase * b = new CFooBase();          
    ExceptionFnk(); 
    delete b; 

}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    try {
        DoAction() ;
    }
    catch( ExceptionBar& e ) {
        printf( "Higher, Exception: %s, magic number %d\n", e.what(), e.Get() ) ; 
    } catch (...) {
        printf( "Catch all, should not happen.\n" ) ; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Produces this output:

```
Created CFooBase (1)
Higher, Exception: ExceptionBar, Magic number 99
```

I am trying not to use smart pointers if possible, as it will overly complicate the system.

**My question is:**

- How do I clean up the memory in `DoAction()` before passing up the exception to the higher levels, without using a smart pointer. ?

Comment: It's more complicated to use raw pointers than smart ones.

Comment: Just use a smart pointer and get over your ridiculous prejudice?!

Comment: Retrofitting exception handling to a system that was designed without exceptions is going to get messy one way or another. You have a number of options, but there is no ideal solution. You could use smart pointers (which you may want to explain why you cannot/do not want to use). You can use try-catch handlers and free resources there. This leads to duplicating code that frees the resources. You could also install an exception handling layer in between the existing code and code that throws exceptions. For that to work you will have to contrive a mechanism to communicate error modes as well.

Comment: @KerrekSB AS I mentioned, I do not want to use smart pointers. They may be the right solution for some problems but not for this one. Don't be rude.

Comment: @Stevensmethurst: I'm not being rude. I'm just trying to say that this *is* a good use case for a smart pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
void DoAction() {
  CFooBase * b = new CFooBase();          
  try
  {
      ExceptionFnk();
  }
  catch(...)
  {
     delete b;
     throw;
  }
  delete b; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering the question I asked.

Answer (score 5):

You can make a deletion SBRM-guard:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct sbrm_deleter
{
    static_assert(std::is_array<T>::value == false,
                  "Must use unsized array type");

    T * ptr;
    sbrm_deleter(T * p = nullptr) : ptr(p) { }
    sbrm_deleter(sbrm_deleter const &) = delete;
    sbrm_deleter & operator=(sbrm_deleter const &) = delete;
    ~sbrm_deleter() { delete ptr; }
};

template <typename T>
struct sbrm_deleter<T[]>
{
    T * ptr;
    sbrm_deleter(T * p = nullptr) : ptr(p) { }
    sbrm_deleter(sbrm_deleter const &) = delete;
    sbrm_deleter & operator=(sbrm_deleter const &) = delete;
    ~sbrm_deleter() { delete [] ptr; }
};
```

Usage:

```
{
    CFooBase * b = new CFooBase;
    sbrm_deleter<CFooBase> _(b);

    // dangerous code
    // don't say "delete" manually
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create it on the stack? It will be cleaned up by stack unwinding when an exception's thrown:

```
void DoAction() {
    CFooBase b;          
    ExceptionFnk(); 
}
```